# Mercurial ignore file

Tags: mercurial, ignore, hgignore

I'm trying to get Mercurial to ignore a configuration file, but I'm failing to get it working.

I have created a repository on my server with `hg init` and cloned that repository to my computer.  I then want to be able to edit the configurationj file but not commit those changes back to the server.

I have tried creating a `.hgignore` in the root of my clone, but Mercurial flags the file with a `?` and whether I commit it or not it still continues to log my configuration changes.

Am I creating the `.hgignore` file in the wrong place, does this file need to be commited? Does it need to be created before I init the repository on the server?

Answer (score 70):

- .hgignore does not need to be created before init
- It the config file will be used by others, you'd better commit the .hgignore so others dont have to create it, *but this is not needed for mercurial to ignore your local files* (see example)
- Yes .hgignore has to be in the root directory

#### Simple example.

Init the repo:

```
$ mkdir test 
$ cd test 
$ hg init
```

Create a file

```
$ touch foo 
$ hg st 
? foo
```

Now create a .hgignore, in the root directory of your repo:

```
$ echo 'foo' > .hgignore
```

`foo` is now ignored:

```
$ hg st 
? .hgignore
```

Note that .hgignore does not need to be committed for this to work.

#### A bit more tricky

If both the config file and a .hgignore (ignoring the config file) are committed in the repo, then yes, the config file changes will be tracked (in other words, .hgignore will have no effect)

Creating config and commit it

```
$ touch config
$ hg ci config -Am 'adding conf'
```

Ignore it:

```
$ echo 'config' >> .hgignore
```

Commit .hgignore:

```
$ hg ci .hgignore -Am '.hgignore'
```

Then if you clone the repo:

```
$ cd ..
$ hg clone test other-user
$ cd other-user
```

and modify config:

```
$ echo 'new config param' >> config
```

then hg will show the changes:

```
$ hg st
M config
```

#### How to deal with this?

You probably want to have a main default configuration file, that is versioned, in the repository, `global.cfg`

And you will ask users to create a `local.cfg` where they will put their local settings. And your script will source the `local.cfg` if present: the local settings override the global ones. Of course, add a line to `.hgignore` to ignore `local.cfg` ;)

Alternative: no global config file, only a `config.example` that users copy and modify locally. The con here is that you will not keep track easily of changes between versions.

Comment: Should the config file be part of the main repo?  If it is and I pull it down won't it already be part of the clone, so hgignore will have no effect?

Comment: True, it will have no effect. See my edit for possible solutions :)

Comment: The best way is to make your application load global.cfg first, and then local.cfg if it exists. Then add global.cfg to Mercurial and add "local.cfg" to .hgignore. That will let you version the defaults in global.cfg and the users can still override them as necessary in the local.cfg file. The important thing to remember is that .hgignore can only ignore files *not* tracked by Mercurial. So if you add "*.cfg" to .hgignore, the global.cfg file will still be committed as normal.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the root directory. Still can't get mine to work when I clone but it barks when I don't have the config file in the pointed-at directory so I must be doing something else wrong.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644174/mercurial-globally-ignore-files

Answer (score 29):

Even if you have ignored files, Mercurial will track them once they have been added to the repository.

To remove your config file from the repository, you can use

```
hg remove -Af file.cfg
```

This will remove the file from from the repository (once committed) without deleting your local file.  See `hg help remove`  However, there is now a delete recorded in the repo, and **Mercurial will remove that file when your or anyone else updates across that revision**.

You could also rename it and have people copy the master to their local file, but you will need to coordinate updates of the local file.

```
hg rename file.cfg file.cfg.example
```

Answer (score 15):

Add the .hgignore file itself to the .hgignore file:

```
syntax: glob

.hgignore
```

or, just check the .hgignore file in to your local clone...

Comment: Per your requirement, to not want to push the .hgignore back to any sources, I would recommend this simple approach. Use a local .hgignore which you do not commit, and add whatever you want to it, placing .hgignore first.
If you check .hgignore into your local clone, you might inadvertantly push it back some day.