# Confused situation with Mercurial

Tags: python, django, mercurial

I'm in this situation:

First of all I just started to use mercurial.
I've a server where there's a my django project.

I want to clone repository from the project dir on server in my local computer.

I've done this:

```
user@host> cd myproject
user@host> hg init
user@host> hg add
user@host> hg commit -m "Added initial files."
```

I've cloned the repo with `hg clone ssh://user@host//path/to/project`. And it's ok, on my computer I've all files that I've on the server.

Now, I want to edit `settings.py` for setting local environment (database engine and other stuff), but I don't want to update the `settings.py` on the server. And after the edit, `hg status` returns me `M settings.py`. Even if I set `echo 'settings.py' > .hgignore` in my local repo, it doesn't work. The same for the directories `static`, `media` and the database `my_database` in the working directory. How can I set mercurial for **NOT** update and commit in the server?

I want to work either on my computer and on the server and get all two repo always synchronized.

Could someone kindly explain me what should I do? I'm a bit confused.

Thank you!

Comment: I can figure out settings.py, but why don't you want static/media synced?

Comment: Because in static there's `django.contrib.auth` static files (admin panel with css, js) and in media there are avatar images, site images and other stuff. Only media/css and media/js contains my files that I want to be synced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't answer your question directly, but I've found a good way to manage local settings is by putting them in a separate file (ignored by your SCM) and loading them in settings.py.

For example, put this at the bottom of settings.py:

```
 try:
   import settings_local
 except ImportError:
   pass  # Ignore when file doesn't exist
```

Anything in `settings_local.py` will override the values in `settings.py`.

**EDIT**:

More directly to your question, see this answer under [Mercurial ignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965303/mercurial-ignore-file/965344#965344). It looks like ignoring an already-versioned file isn't supported. I have done it with Subversion before, so I can see why you are trying it. The other answers have some workarounds.

Comment: Can't you *remove* the file from Mercurial records, and then ignore it?

Comment: @Eli  I'm sure you can (see the other answers), but this is a much better practice in the long-term if you can make the initial change.

Comment: I agree that the first part of your answer is a good way to address the OP's problem. Just replied strictly on the .hgignore comment

Answer (score 2):

First, if `settings.py` is already committed, then ignoring it won't change that.  You'd need to first

```
$ hg remove settings.py
$ echo 'glob:settings.py' > .hgignore
```

(Just appending the filename to `.hgignore` doesn't do anything, that I know of, but I know there are different formats for this.  Anyway, be aware of that, as well.)

Comment: True, but apparently not what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer one part of your question:

If a file matches a pattern in the ignore file (.hgignore), it is NOT ignored if it is already being tracked by mercurial. This explains why edits to your settings.py are NOT ignored; it's because settings.py is already being tracked. When you did the command `hg add`, that added all the files into your repository; that is, mercurial started tracking them all (except any that were being ignored at the time).