# Mercurial: Globally Ignore Files

Tags: mercurial, hgignore, hgrc

I know about `.hgignore` and how I can ignore files on a project-by-project basis. I want to ignore stuff for all Mercurial repositories.

Is there something I can stick in `.hgrc`? Or put a `.hgignore` in my `$HOME` path (I tried that already but maybe I did something wrong).

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can add a path to a global or per-user ignore file in the [`[ui]` section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui) of your global/user `hgrc` or `Mercurial.ini`:

```
[ui]
ignore = ~/.hgignore
```

On Windows:

```
[ui]
ignore = %USERPROFILE%\.hgignore
```

Comment: The tilda will work on window too -- mercurial interpolates it to USERPROFILE for you.

Comment: @zerkms: Seems that site expired almost a month ago. :/

Comment: @Joel B Fant: it's sad :-( there were a lot of good patterns for different kind of projects

Comment: Just FYI, `~/.hgignore` seems to work on Windows as well, at least with Windows 7 mercurial version 3.0.2. It works the same as the `%USERPROFILE%` macro listed in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In powershell, you can get to your global files like this.

```
PS> notepad $env:userprofile/mercurial.ini
...
[ui]
ignore = %USERPROFILE%\.hgignore
...

PS> notepad $env:userprofile/.hgignore
/bin/
/obj/
```