# Override the global ignore?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

In my global `.hgignore` file, I'm ignoring files in the `packages/` directory. In this one repo, I want to *not* ignore that folder.

Is it possible to *un* ignore a file that has been ignored by a previous `.hgignore`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the technique for globally ignoring files [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644174/mercurial-globally-ignore-files), then you can override the global ignore locally via editing the repo's hgrc:

Add the following to the file at `\.hg\hgrc`

```
[ui]
ignore=.hgignore
```

This is the local override of the global set in your `%userprofile%\Mercurial.ini` (or other files in the [config cascade](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) and tells Mercurial to use the `.hgignore` file at the root of the repo.

Note that this method then uses *none* of the global ignore file, so the parts you want to use will need to be in the local `.hgignore`.

Comment: Ah well, I guess that's the best that can be done, without writing my own extension of course. Thanks.