# mercurial and ignore pattern

Tags: mercurial, ignore, hgignore

I'm trying to get mercurial to ignore diffs. I performed the following according to [Mercurial ignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965303/mercurial-ignore-file):

```
$ echo "*.diff" >> .hgignore
```

Status now give me an error (I added the '...' for readability):

```
$ hg status
abort: .../.hgignore: invalid pattern (relre): *.diff
```

Searching the web for the error message returned a few non-relevant results. Any ideas on how to ignore diff files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write first:
`syntax: glob`

Fully .hgignore

```
syntax: glob

*.diff
```

The default regex. You can write all the regular expression, then switch to syntax glob. Example:

```
\.pyc$
test\.py$

syntax: glob
*.diff
```

If you want to exclude all but a few, it is better to use a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks crazyzubr. How do I turn off globbing after the `*.diff` entry?

Comment: If you only want one line to use glob you can use glob:*.diff otherwise you can switch to regex using, on a single line, syntax: regexp